# Perform function within code, write the result to sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I have data in A1:A10

The data needs to be split using the "=" delimiter. For instance:

Name = Popeye

Occupation = Sailor Man

I can do this on the sheet level by inserting this function in range B1

```
=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(TRIM(REGEXEXTRACT("="&A3:A16,"^"&TRIM(REPT("=+[^=]+",COLUMN(OFFSET(A1,,,1,2))-1)&"=+([^=]+)")))))
```

(thanks to AdamL for that function)

However I would simply like to perform that function within the code and overwrite the original data with the result.

So if I capture the values in a variable, such as...

```
var multiVals = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("test").getRange("A1:A10").getValues();
```

How can I then apply that function to the variable so that I can overwrite the orignal data in A1:A10 with the results of that function?

(the results would be in range A1:B10, of course. As there is one "=" per record and both sides of the "=" are needed. So two columns are necessary for the result)

Btw, as a tack-on to that, suppose I only wanted everything to the right of the "=". That's not needed in this particular case, but it would certainly be helpful for future reference. (am I pushing my luck?)

Answer (score 1):

You'd use a for loop and split the string, or use regEx if everything after the first equals. The split would get everything until a second equals.

```
var bCol = [];
var currVal;
for( lin in multiVals ){
  currVal = multiVals[lin][0].split('=');
  bCol.push([currVal[0], currVal [1]]);
}
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("test").getRange("A1:B10").setValues(bCol);
```

As regEx, all after equals in the second column:

```
var bCol = [];
var currVal;
for( lin in multiVals ){
   currVal = /^([^=]*)=(.*)/.exec(multiVals[lin][0]);
   bCol.push([currVal[1], currVal[2]])
}

SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("test").getRange("A1:B10").setValues(bCol);
```

Comment: Thank you Kriggs. A couple of things however. Is there a way to incorporate the TRIM function to that first SPLIT version? I need to eliminate any/all trailing and leading spaces.  Also, the regEx version did not work for me at all. I am not yet comfortable with my understanding of what you have offered, so I'm still trying to figure out the workings of it. Push is not something that I understand in this context as of yet.

Comment: @5th4x4 Yes, you can incorporate it, play with regEx in (regEx101)[https://regex101.com/] or any other site. The regEx did not work because of some exception, debug it and find why, I have it going just fine if all the values in A1 to A10 has an equals, if not, you need to treat that exception. Push inserts a new value into the next free index of an Array, I'm pushing another Array into the Array, because setValues asks for an Array of arrays ([][]).

Comment: Unfortunately the leading and trailing spaces (whitespace) do not exist prior to splitting. Therefore adding to the regEx to remove them does not resolve the issue, since they appear after the split. Further complicating matters is that sometimes there is not a space either before or after the "=".... although most of the time there is at least one space on either side of it. So that makes splitting on " = " unreliable. TRIM resolves that when nested in the function that I was using. But unless it's possible to replicate the function within the code itself, a sheet-level solution is required.

Comment: @5th4x4 SO is a way to go where you end in a roadblock, not where you go when you don't want to have the trouble to code it yourself, all your questions could be accomplished using a combination of regEx, if's, loops and such, if you don't want to take the time to code it yourself  hire a programmer, if you tried and arrived in a point you don't understand, come back with the code.

Comment: I really must apologize if you are feeling as though I've come to SO to take advantage of the community here (in general) and you (specifically). Nothing could be further from the truth, and I believe that my reputation here would support that (not that I expect anyone to be aware of my insignificant reputation here - although if I had a bad reputation here, that would more likely be better known). In truth I have spent many hours researching and learning what I can about in-code solutions such as this - much to the dismay of the powers who pay me my salary. (I'll continue...)

Comment: …Anyway, I was instructed to provide a working solution for NOW, and that I should pursue my research of the ideal solution for another time. So that is what I had to do (an imposed roadblock). As for your help with this issue, I am as grateful to you as I am to all who take time out of their day to assist me. I have always been courteous and appreciative - and I extend that to you as well. I will put an apparently overdue up arrow on your answer for now, and when I have the time to pursue the solution to my original question, I will post that solution and then mark this as solved.